# Laravel no me registra un dato que va con el array

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema al registrar un dato desde Laravel. Estoy usando el formulario de la imagen

**Versión de laravel 6**

[image: formulario de registro]

La cuestión es que hay un campo que debo guardar en la base de datos y lo envío directamente desde el controlador , es del usuario logueado.

El codigo del controlador es este:

```
public function store(CreateCompanyRequest $request)
{

    try{
    $data = [
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'company_type' => $request->input('company_type'),
        'administrator_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'address' => $request->input('address'),
        'city_id' => $request->input('city_id'),
        'province_id' => $request->input('province_id'),
        'country_id' => $request->input('country_id'),
        'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
        'other_phone' => $request->input('other_phone'),
        'fax' => $request->input('fax'),
        'tax_id' => $request->input('tax_id'),
        'about' => $request->input('about'),
        'sector_id' => $request->input('sector_id'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'website' => $request->input('website'),

    ];

        Company::create($data);

        return redirect()->route('company.index')->with('success', 'El registro se ha realizado con éxito !');

    }catch(\Exception $e){

        return redirect()->route('company.index')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver el **tercer campo corresponde al usuario logueado**.

Reviso el $data con un dd y muestra todos los campos, incluido el de administrator_id.

[image: dd realiado en el controlador antes de Company::create($data)]

La cuestión es que registra todos los datos excepto el administrator_id.

[image: Aparece el registro exitoso]

En la base de datos no lo registra a pesar de decir exitoso

[image: En la base de datos no lo registra]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar el campo administrator_id es llave foranea que apunta a usuarios.

Comment: Revisa si en el modelo que usas(Company) el campo id esta oculto

Comment: Gracias Joel, el problema estaba en que no estaba ese campo en el array fillable del modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aveces pasa que no esta el campo en el modelo, fijate que en el modelo Company, tengas en fillable el campo administrator_id, casi siempre pasa porque no colocamos ese campo en el modelo.

Comment: Vale @AnySlehider .... sabes. no habia caido en cuenta de ello voy a revisarlo, seguramente esta ahi el problema.

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema acabo de solucionarlo, habia pasado por alto poner ese campo en el array fillable.. Muchas gracias